# How do I change a complexType in XML/XSD with restrictions to work with mixed values (integer and string)?

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, restriction, complextype

Hi, I've got this task to do for e-learning session in XML. I need to limit every string value and every integer value occurring inside of the xml(elements and attributes). I've had no problems with handling the cases were those values are of the same type, I am struggling with how it's supposed to work when one is integer and the other string.

The xml files looks like this.

```
  <car id="5">
        <brand origin="Italy">Lamorghini</brand>
        <model body="sedan">Huracan</model>
        <year>2017</year>
        <cc engineType="gasoline">5204</cc>
        <registered>Switzerland</registered>
    </car>
```

Right now I'm focusing on the element **"cc"**  which is my main concern. As I understand since it has an attribute It can only be **complexType**, but because the value of the element is integer(which is a simpleType) the validator gives an error.

```
 <xsd:complexType name="TypeCC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="330"/>
            <xsd:maxInlcusive value="8277"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

I tried multiple ways, but none of them worked, I assume I am missing some understanding. Validator specifices **base type**  as the thing to be concerned as expected.

I also wanted to know if every attribute in the above xml is supposed to be placed outside of `<xsd:sequence/>`, but inside the **complexType** of the **element car**? As shown below by example?

```
<xsd:complexType name="TypeCar">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="brand" type="TypeBrand"/>
        .
        .
        .
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
        .
        .
    <xsd:attribute name="engineType" type="TypeEngine"/>
</xsd:complexType
```

Be forgiving for my lack of posting skills, it's my first ever here. To sum it up I want to know how to solve the issues with mixed types and the correct placement of attributes. Thanks a lot for any answers.

Comment: You can define `cc` either by first extending the xsd:integer type into a 'complex type with simple content' (in this step you can add the attribute) and then restricting it to the appropriate range, or by first restricting it to the appropriate range and then defining a complex type which extends it.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the `TypeCC` the only i know to do that is using an extra complextype as base for `TypeCC`. for example:

```
<xsd:element name="cc" type="tns:TypeCC"></xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="BaseTypeCC" mixed="true">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:attribute name='engineType' type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:extension>        
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TypeCC" mixed="false">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="tns:BaseTypeCC">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="330"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="8277"/>
        </xsd:restriction>      
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

reagarding the question

> I also wanted to know if every attribute in the above xml is supposed
>   to be placed outside of <xsd:sequence/>, but inside the complexType of
>   the element car?

**No** only attribute of the `car` element goes there. The others goes in the content-model definition of its own element.

Comment: I was thinking about that. but I got tunneled on the idea that there must be an easier, quicker and more reading friendly solution to it. I had, to do even more complicated variation of the code you've given me, but I'm really grateful for the help. Everything works just fine and I got the grasp of it. Consider the question closed.

Comment: Nice to help.
You can also accept/upvote my answer to better close the question :)
see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers